# Error message from simple SELECT statement with practice database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the AdventureWorks practice database attached to SQL Server 2012.

A simple statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Shift;
```

gives me this error:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'AdventureWorks2012'.

I also tried:

```
USE master
GO
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Shift;
```

Received same error message. Any idea to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that AdventureWorks2012 is the name of the table? I'm pretty sure is the name of the database.  do Use AdventureWorks2012 GO  Select * from table name

Comment: Does that table exist?

Comment: I apologize for the eror that is the database. I ment to copy paste the table names. I will correct it, it happens with whatever table I type.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misspelling of the database name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is AdventureWorks2012 the name of a database or a table?

```
USE <database name>
```

means use the specified database to run the query against.

```
SELECT * FROM <table name>
```

means select all the rows from the specified table.

--Edit because of change in question--

You don't want to use Master, you want to use the name of your DB.  Next, using the object explorer, I would make sure the table actually exists in the Database you created.

Comment: I apologize for the error, i meant to c/p the table. I re corrected my post. It happens with any table I use.

Comment: Perfect. Using Master was my problem. Thank you for the thorough explanation and clarification.